# Best practice for Rails controller that paginates one mime format but not another

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, will-paginate

My rails project is paginating the HTML format but not the the others.  Can someone suggest a more elegant approach to dealing with the difference in getting the @contacts collection?  Perhaps the pagination version should be a different method that only supports HTML?

```
def index
  if request.format.to_sym == :html
    @contacts = Contact.paginate(page: params[:page]).search(params[:search])
  else
    @contacts = Contact.search(params[:search])
  end      

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render html: @contacts }
    format.mobile { render mobile: @contacts }
    format.json { render json: @contacts }
    format.xml { render xml: @contacts.to_xml }
  end
end
```

My solution was to add paginate as a RESTful resource in routes.rb which automagically gives me the route helper method: paginate_contacts_path

```
resources :contacts do
  collection do
    get 'paginate'
  end
end
```

and to have a separate paginate method in ContactsController

```
def index
  @contacts = Contact.search(params[:search])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render html: @contacts }
    format.mobile { render mobile: @contacts }
    format.json { render json: @contacts }
    format.xml { render xml: @contacts.to_xml }
  end
end

def paginate
  @contacts = Contact.paginate(page: params[:page]).search(params[:search])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strongly prefer a separate method because this creates inconstancies and makes the piece less testable. Also you would, in for example documentation, need to create exceptions.

Another way is to handle this with some parameter. Now it suddenly (when you only change views) returns different data. That might look like an error for an unknown developer and might raise issues.

So don't do it magically, clear parameter or separate method.

Comment: Using the will-paginate gem adds pagination params auto-magically but i think you are suggesting (and i agree) there should be a def paginate method that I either 1) reference explicitly everywhere instead of contacts_path or 2) simply have contacts_path redirected to ContactsController::paginate.  If I chose #2, how should I do that?

Comment: It became obvious that I should do #2 and I did that by adding 'paginate' to my RESTful resource (shown above)

Comment: Nice! Yes think you got the clue of what I think about it. It's really about being clear to developers now and in the future who have to work on your project. Good luck with your project!